# Check whether an object derived from enable_shared_from_this is managed by shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, shared-ptr

Suppose I have a class derived from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

```
struct foo
  : std::enable_shared_from_this<foo>
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> get_shared()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }

    bool is_shared() const
    {
        /* implementation ??? */
    }
};

foo  A;
auto S= A.get_shared();   // UB (pre c++17) or exception (c++17)
```

Prior to c++17, there appears to be no way to detect whether an object `foo` is actually managed by a `shared_ptr`. Correct?

But even for c++17, I'm not sure how to best implement such a detection. One obvious approach is

```
bool foo::is_shared() const
{
    try {
        shared_from_this();
    } catch(...) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But can the `try`-`catch` be avoided? Can I use [`weak_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this)? How?

Comment: `foo A; auto A=get_shared(); ` what this supposed to do?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Sorry, typo. fixed now.

Comment: `weak_from_this().use_count()` should work

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks. Taken your advice and removed it.

Comment: "_actually managed_" What if it is not "managed" by one? What would you do?

Comment: @curiousguy not invoke UB but rather throw an exception, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement `is_shared` leveraging `weak_from_this()` in C++17 like:

```
bool is_shared() const
{
    return !weak_from_this().expired();
}
```

This is exception free and will only return `true` is the object is actually managed by a `shared_ptr`.

Pre C++17 there isn't a way to check since it is undefined behavior to call `shared_from_this()` when the object is not owned by a `shared_ptr`.  It wasn't until `weak_from_this()` was introduced in C++17 that we could access the private `weak_ptr` member of `std::enable_shared_from_this` (via a copy) that we can inspect the state in a defined manner.

Comment: I don't understand your argument why there is no way prior to C++17. Yes, calling `shared_from_this()` is UB, but the `weak_ptr` was there already (though I reckon that was not specified)

Comment: @Walter It's there but you can't access it.  It is a private member of `std::enable_shared_from_this`.  It wasn't until C++17 that we are given access to the member (via a copy).

Comment: Starting from C++17, calling `shared_from_this()` is equivalent to `shared_­ptr<T>(weak_­this)` where `weak_this` is an "exposition only" weak pointer. Also, `shared_from_this` no longer has a precondition. I take this to mean that it is now defined behavior to call `shared_from_this()` on a never-shared object, and it will throw `bad_weak_ptr` (as most implementations probably always did).

Comment: @ArneVogel Correct.  It is now defined and it will throw an exception.  Pre C++17 it wasn't defined and there was no way to check if you could call `shared_from_this`